# Incremental or full data load in oracle table

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

We have below scenario.

We are receiving data in a `file`. We will upload the same in `DB table`. Next time we will get only incremental data. so from next time we don't have to upload entire data but only the incremental data. filename will be same whether data is incremental or full. so basically first time we have to `insert` the record and from next time on wards we have to `update` the record. `Scheduler` will send the file every day. timestamp of file will be different, rest everything will be same.
Can you suggest logic for the same in `PL/SQL`

along with above the full scenario is below
we will receive file is in zip format.
first we will unzip file. if file is `".csv"` then we have to update or insert the data. if after unzipping file it is `".pscsv"` (its internal format) then this file contains the primary key. based on primary key we will delete the record from target database. so if
1) .csv then upload or insert
2) .pscsv then delete the record

Answer (score 2):

From what you described, if you used that file as an **external table** and `merge` command (which is also called an "upsert", as it is capable of performing `insert` and `update` within a single statement) to fill the target table, well - you could consider that as one option which, actually, might perform quite well.

Comment: actually I have to upload in external table.I think I will have to do the same what you suggested. by using dbms_cloud package I have to upload because file reside in cloud. could you give me some syntax for that.

Comment: "Data in a file" you receive is the external table. It is source of data. It is then read and inserted into the target table. Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with the DBMS_CLOUD package (never even heard of it) so - I can't assist with that, sorry.

Comment: I have updated the question. you can help me with utl_file or external table or sqlloader or anything else. anything will work. i will convert the same in dbms_cloud.

Comment: I’d never heard of `dbms_cloud` either but the syntax is available [online](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/autonomous-data-warehouse-cloud/user/dbmscloud-reference.html), with more details at https://antognini.ch/2018/07/dbms_cloud-package-a-reference-guide. It appears to contain a procedure to create an external table.